# How to choose between durations with different probability of success?

Tags: probability

Suppose I am playing a free game that may give me a teddy bear. The game can be played an unlimited number of times. I am given 4 choices, each with a different probability of being given the teddy bear, but each probability has a different "wait time" (i.e. the time between turns, or the time I have to wait for the result to be announced). My goal is to get a single teddy bear in the least amount of time.

Refer to the table below. The "probability" column in the table below shows the probability of winning the prize. The "wait duration" column shows the amount of time I have to wait between turns to play again.

```
choice | probability | wait duration (days)
-------------------------------------------
A      | 0.10        | 1
B      | 0.60        | 2
C      | 0.85        | 3
D      | 0.97        | 4
```

For example, if I choose C now (probability 0.85), I will have to wait 3 days before I am given the result (i.e. win or lose). During these 3 days, I am not allowed to play the game again. I will only be allowed to play the game again once the result of the previous game is known.

My question is: which choice should I choose in order to get the teddy bear as soon as possible?

From my understanding of the geometric distribution, the expected total duration for the choices are:

```
choice | expected total wait (days)
-----------------------------------
A      | 1/0.10     = 10
B      | (1/0.60)*2 = 3.33
C      | (1/0.85)*3 = 3.52
D      | (1/0.97)*4 = 4.12
```

Therefore, B is the best choice. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: Seems correct to me. You use the geometric distribution and multiply the number of rounds by the time you have to wait. I do not see any tripwires in the question.

Comment: Your question is ill-posed. It depends on what you mean by "as soon as possible". If you have just one day for instance, you have to choose option A. A more robust way to solve the problem is to define a function over the number of days $f(N)$ that gives you how good is for you to have the bear at day $N$ ($f$ should be decreasing of course). Then you try to maximise your expected $E[f]$ over the possible strategies.